# Select multiple columns of count for different column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables like this:

```
ID          Status
----------- -----------------
a            3
b            3
c            1
d            2
e            1
```

How can i query it such that the count for each status is in 1 column:

```
Status=1  Status=2   Status=3
--------  --------  --------
2          1          2
```

is it necessary to `Select` from multiple `Select` of `Count` here?
NOTE: the Status is not fixed and may contain values besides 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Is Status column dynamic? Is that fix that it will contain 1,2,3 only?

Comment: Nope, it's not fix

Comment: Then see my ans in Answers.. that can help you with different values

Answer (score 4):

Use Conditional Aggregate

```
select count(case when Status = 1 then 1 end) as [Status=1],
       count(case when Status = 2 then 1 end) as [Status=2],
       count(case when Status = 3 then 1 end) as [Status=3]
From yourtable
```

same count can be achieved through `SUM` aggregate

```
Sum(case when Status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Status=1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, This is dynamic

```
select 'Status = '+cast(Status as varchar(200)) Status,count(Status) Count from yourtable group by Status
```

Comment: Upvoted... But changes the result format.. probably OP can follow this format which avoid's hard coding

Comment: Thank you for your vote @prdp but converting it to pivot would also get ugly.so i kept it this way.